# how to filter by using value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide .tab when I click .btn in another div.
but this code doesn't work.
I don't want to use filter by index for some reasons

How Can I fix it?

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var tabname = $(this).parent().attr("id")

  $(".tab").filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("value") === tabname
  }).hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab01">
  <button class="btn"> button</button>
</div>
<div id="tab02">
  <button class="btn"> button</button>
</div>
<div id="tab03">
  <button class="btn"> button</button>
</div>

<div class="tab-list">
  <button class="tab" value="#tab01">This is button 1</button>
  <button class="tab" value="#tab02">This is button 2</button>
  <button class="tab" value="#tab03">This is button 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.tab').hide()` perhaps? The use case isn't clear from the code in the question.

Comment: `$(this).attr("value")` is returning `#tab01` whereas you are comparing id i.e. `tab01` with `#tab01`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - your HTML was invalid as well as the error of having the # in the value of the button

Answer (score 0):

Basically I fixed the code, but instead of hiding do you not want to `hide` all then `show` the selected?

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var tabname = $(this).parent().attr("id")
  console.log(tabname)

  $(".tab").filter(function(index, elem) {
    return $(elem).attr("value") === '#' + tabname
  }).hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab01">
  <button class="btn"> tab 1</button>
</div>
<div id="tab02">
  <button class="btn"> tab 2</button>
</div>
<div id="tab03">
  <button class="btn"> tab 3</button>
</div>

<div class="tab-list">
  <button class="tab" value="#tab01">This is tab content 1</button>
  <button class="tab" value="#tab02">This is tab content 2</button>
  <button class="tab" value="#tab03">This is tab content 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a CSS-selector instead of a filter:

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
 let sel='.tab[value="#'+this.closest("div").id+'"]';
 // console.log(sel)
 $(sel).hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab01">
  <button class="btn"> button</button>
</div>
<div id="tab02">
  <button class="btn"> button</button>
</div>
<div id="tab03">
  <button class="btn"> button</button>
</div>

<div class="tab-list">
  <button class="tab" value="#tab01">This is button 1</button>
  <button class="tab" value="#tab02">This is button 2</button>
  <button class="tab" value="#tab03">This is button 3</button>
</div>
```